# How to display a date in a european format in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a date which I want to display in a view in a european format dd/mm/yyyy.
I have a table called album and its attribute called data_rilascio is a date saved yyyy/mm/dd format
I want to keep the date in the database the way it is and just to display it in the european format.

```
<small class="text-muted">8 brani - {{$album->data_rilascio}}</small>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert date format in dd/mm/yyyy through laravel Eloquent Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681579/insert-date-format-in-dd-mm-yyyy-through-laravel-eloquent-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it this way:

```
$album->data_rilascio->format('d/m/Y')
```

or

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($album->data_rilascio))
```